# IBM Worklight - Server configuration from application?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-runtime

we are devloping an application using IBM worklight.
we have a requirement that the worklight server may be deployed in other location(that is ip will be changing).
can the app be configured to communicate to the other server through some settings page with out being reinstalled ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and No.

The official response is that this is not a supported configuration. IBM Worklight will not support this if done.

Technically, you have 2 options:

1. Use the Worklight Settings page (enabled by default in application-descriptor.xml; Android and iOS only)

   - In iOS it is external to the app, accessible via Preferences.app
   - In Android it is accessible via the Options Menu (which is not present starting API Level 13 or so)
   - This feature **is not meant for end-user consumption**; you must enter URLs manually. This is not encouraged for anything other than testing
   - This feature is not customizable
2. Create your own app-level settings page and follow this: [Re-route/Divert some WL.Client Adapter Invocation traffic to WL Server through different URL (for PCI payment and security requirements)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258784/re-route-divert-some-wl-client-adapter-invocation-traffic-to-wl-server-through-d)

   - Again, this is not encouraged. There will not be support provided if this path is chosen

If you feel this is important to your customer, [you can submit an RFE and explain your use case](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/connect.html) for future consideration by Worklight product designers.